# Can I use an externalId field to be the integration key between Marketing cloud and sales cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm starting an integration marketing cloud and salescloud. My salescloud data is from another system and we use an externalId key to upsert the data.
My question is only the marketingcloud action events can be triggered using an externalId field instead of the contactId.

If so, we can have other fields to reference to subscribeId.

Answer (score 1):

The Marketing Cloud Connector works with Salesforce Ids to handle the integration and you can't change that. When you sync your data with synchronized data sources the data relations between your objects are established automatically in the Contact Builder data model based on Salesforce Ids. Also tracking will only be pushed back into the CRM if the addressed contacts/leads in your data extensions are connected to all subscribers (on Subscriberkey) by the Contact ID or Lead ID.

However, you can still import the external Ids (check the fields when you setup the sync) to have them in the Marketing Cloud. They could be used to create data relationships in email studio (for filters) or when you have other external integrations by API that require those external Ids.